# SafariExtension messageEvent

Tags: safari-extension, safari

i'm trying to make a SafariExtension but i have some issue with the messaging Api, in fact the example in the doc don't work, this: [Safari Message Proxies](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/documentation/Tools/Conceptual/SafariExtensionGuide/MessagesandProxies/MessagesandProxies.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009977-CH14-SW2)

so What work and what don't work ?
 I can call the function on the global page from a injected script.
 I can't send a response to the injected script.

here what i have:

injected:

```
safari.self.tab.dispatchMessage("foo", "bar");
```

no need more, the bug is in the global html.

global:

```
safari.application.addEventListener("message", function ( e ) {
 if (e.name != 'foo')
   return false;
 e.target.page.dispatchMessage("bar", 'foo'); <-- Undefined on page ...
},false);
```

as i mention the 4th line on the global page always fails, so i can't send back an answer
to the injected script ...

no clue on the documentation since this is almost extracted form the doc.

Comment: Are you listening for messages in the injected script? safari.self.addEventListener("bar", getAnswer, false);

Answer (score 0):

You need to include a listener in the target page. For example...

```
safari.self.addEventListener("message", function(e) {
    if(e.name == 'bar') {
        alert(e.message);
        // 'foo' would be alerted to the user, as it is the message content.
    };
}, false);
```

Messages are one-way transactions, so sending a message to the global page and receiving a message on the target page are two completely separate events. A listener is needed on both sides of the exchange.